# nfs share accessible from one computer but access denied from another one

Tags: permissions, nfs

I set up a nfs share on my raspberry pi following this : https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/nfs.md
My /etc/exports looks like this :

```
pi@nextcloudpi:~ $ cat /etc/exports 
/export 192.168.1.0/24(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
/export/users   192.168.1.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

I mounted it on my desktop (ubuntu 20.04) without any problem using this :

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 192.168.1.48:/ /mnt
```

Problem is, when I try to mount it on my laptop, which has pretty much the exact same ubuntu as my desktop, i get an error :

```
laptop:~$ sudo mount -t nfs -vvvv -o proto=tcp,port=2048 192.168.1.48:/ /mnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Feb 25 18:22:35 2021
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'proto=tcp,port=2048,vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.48,clientaddr=192.168.1.67'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection refused
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'proto=tcp,port=2048,addr=192.168.1.48'
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.48 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 60769
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.48:/
```

They're both on the same network. The only difference I can think of is that my laptop is Wi-fi connected while my desktop is ethernet plugged in.
Anyone knows what might be the problem ?

Comment: They might not be on the same network if one is on WiFi and the other on ethernet. Use `ip addr` to check the network settings.

Comment: What am i looking for exactly in the ip addr results ? The only difference i notice is the laptop has "noprefixroute". Also, worth noting I have a nfs on the desktop that I can mount on the laptop with no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out a good night's sleep helps out a lot.
If you look closely, I was using port=2049 on the desktop, and port=2048 on the laptop. Correcting the typo was enough to fix it.